# C# How to fix popup alert "Do you want us to try to recover ..." when I try to open excel file

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

On C#, I use openxml to generate excel file and process is success I got excel file. but when I click to open that file I got popup alert "We found a problem with some content in 'zzz.xlsx'. Do you want us to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source the source of this workbook, click Yes."
[image]
When I click Yes I got this popup
[image]
[image]
And the popup not show up for all but that show up when data in excel file is more than 1000 row (approximately) if data is less, the popup not show up.

And the popup not show up for all case but that show up when data in excel file is more than 1000 row (approximately) if data is less, the popup not show up. I don't know why, it about some limit of excel or my code is not correct or my data that generate to execl is wrong. Orz

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why but I couldn't find any answers. If anyone has a solution to not show the popup alert please give me a suggestion, thanks.

My expecting is when I open the Excel file it doesn't show any more popups.

Comment: Get the _OpenXML SDK Productivity Tool_ (I think this is its current hiding place: https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK) it will show you what the errors are. It's an essential tool when doing any OpenXML SDK dev work

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can understand, it seems that you are not writing all the required files/fields. Whenever a required attribute/tag is missing in the xml, Excel will try to repair the file as much as possible and ignore the tags which are not written correctly.

In your case, it seems like either you have added a styling to your cells. This is done by using the attribute s="1" of the cell, where the value represents the style applied.

e.g.

```
<row r="7" spans="4:11">
    <c r="D7" s="1"/> 
</row>
```

As you can see, here i have applied some style in the cell D7.
When you apply a style, it is required that you write the "Style.xml" file.

For more information refer to Part1 and Part2 of ISO/IEC 29500.
These can be downloaded fro these links: [Part1](https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c071691_ISO_IEC_29500-1_2016.zip)   [Part2](https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c077818_ISO_IEC_29500-2_2021(E).zip)